# Recv failure: Connection was reset in Curl PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, curl

I want to fetch some data from 12.96.12.174 this IP address using http post by XML. I create curl PHP code for that

```
 <?php
$url = "http://12.96.12.174";
$post_string = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CRMAcresMessage>
<Header ImmediateResponseRequired="true" OriginalBodyRequested="true">
<MessageID>25</MessageID>
<TimeStamp>2016-03-11T011:35:11</TimeStamp>
<Operation Operand="Request" Data="PlayerProfile" />
</Header>
<PlayerID>59979</PlayerID>
<Body>   
</Body>
</CRMAcresMessage>';
$header  = "POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n"; 
$header .= $post_string;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
//$fp = fopen('rss.xml', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PORT, 8085);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,  $header);
echo $data = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
print curl_error($ch);
else
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

When I hit that link from "http://example.com/members/check.php" this url this gives me `Recv failure: Connection was reset in Curl`.

And from my localhost I got Failed to connect

php version is also >5.3

I am beginner in Curl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

For Recv failure: Connection was reset in Curl PHP ==> 
Declare like this :

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER as 0
```

& make sure that you are using PHP version >5.3